# count occurrences of elements

Tags: scala, list, haskell, dictionary, list-comprehension

Counting all elements in a list is a one-liner in Haskell:

```
count xs = toList (fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])
```

Here is an example usage:

```
*Main> count "haskell scala"
[(' ',1),('a',3),('c',1),('e',1),('h',1),('k',1),('l',3),('s',2)]
```

Can this function be expressed so elegantly in Scala as well?

Comment: Pointless version: `toList . fromListWith (+) . map (,1)`.

Comment: @sdcvvc Are tuple sections now standard Haskell?

Comment: Not H2010, but IMO pretty standard.

Comment: @sdcvvc Where can I find this "imo pretty standard"? ;)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
scala> "haskell scala".groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toSeq
res1: Seq[(Char, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((e,1), (s,2), (a,3), ( ,1), (l,3), (c,1), (h,1), (k,1))
```

Comment: It's a strange definition of shorter ;) But at least it is also a oneliner ;)

Comment: @Nicolas, I didn't have `.toSeq` at end when I wrote that. ;) Removed it now.

Answer (score 6):

Recall `group` from the Data.List library,

```
group :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

giving us:

```
map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

a list-friendly and relatively "naive" implementation.

Comment: Wowo, I didn't know about the `&&&` operator, pretty cool!

Comment: Whilst this is cool, the question was about how one could implement this in *Scala*.

Comment: The question was mistaken in thinking that using an intermediate container and list comprehension was an elegant approach in Haskell :)

Comment: How does your solution compare to mine with respect to time complexity?

Comment: @FredOverflow They have the same complexity.

Comment: Both are Θ(n log n) worst case. In fact, putting items into binary tree and doing infix traversal is a method of sorting. Suppose `sort` takes Θ(n) given an ascending list. Then this solution will be better on [1,2,...,n]. Suppose `sort` always takes Θ(n log n). Then this solution will be worse on [1,1,...,1].

Comment: For anyone landing here: `&&&` can be found in `Control.Arrow`, which can be found out easily by [hoogling](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

Comment: A naive `group . sort` implementation will likely beat a naive `fromListWith` implementation most of the time because most new Haskell users will use `fromListWith` from Data.Map instead of Data.Map.Strict.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation:

```
def count[A](xs: Seq[A]): Seq[(A, Int)] = xs.distinct.map(x => (x, xs.count(_ == x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Going for a literal translation, let's try this:

```
// Implementing this one in Scala
def fromSeqWith[A, B](s: Seq[(A, B)])(f: (B, B) => B) =
    s groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2) reduceLeft f)

def count[A](xs: Seq[A]) = fromSeqWith(xs map (_ -> 1))(_+_).toSeq
```

Scala's `groupBy` makes this more complex than it needs to be -- there have been calls for `groupWith` or `groupInto`, but they didn't make Odersky's standard for standard library inclusion.