# Scala Count Occurrences in Large List

Tags: scala, group-by

In Scala I have a list of tuples `List[(String, String)]`. So now from this list I want to find how many times each unique tuple appears in the list.

One way to do this would be to apply `groupby{ x => x}` and then find the length. But here my data set it quite large and it's taking a lot of time.

So is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: @evan058, Is it really a duplicate? Here the OP is focusing on performance unlike the other question.

Comment: Yes thats why i mentioned one easy way would be just to group. But i needed a better performing approach to it.

Comment: @Sidhant have you tried `.groupBy(identity)` specifically? I guess I assumed the other answers would take performance into account.

Comment: Is groupBy(identity) different from groupBy{ x => x}

Comment: Same effect, not sure about performance

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105418/2661491)?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the counting manually, using a `Map`. Iterate over your collection/list. During the iteration, build a `count` map. Keys in the `count` map are unique items from the original collection/list, values are number of occurrences of the key. If the item being processed during the iteration is in the `count` collection, increase its value by 1. If not, add value 1 to the `count` map. You can use `getOrElse`:

```
count(current_item) = count.getOrElse(current_item, 0) + 1;
```

This should work faster than `groupby`, followed by length check. Will also require less memory.

Other suggestions, check also this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934383/count-occurences-of-elements).

Comment: I think so too, because `groupBy` has a Map under the hood. So storing the lists is unnecessary extra work. It would be nice to know how big the difference is, though.

Comment: In [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105418/2661491) this approach was about the same but I am not sure how the `(String, String)` data would change things.